# Logic gate circuit to close when sensor signal turns ON and then OFF, but must ignore another ON?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, logic-gates, magnetic-flux, reed-switch

I am trying to put a permanent magnet in a transformer between both coils, so that the transformer can utilize the flux from the permanent magnet by guiding its flux periodically.

We have one primary coil that will change the direction of the flux from permanent magnet towards the other secondary coils one by one.
I want primary coil to change polarity when the first secondary coil rate of change of flux becomes zero.

So I'll put a reed switch to detect the magnetic field that causes inducing of voltage into secondary coil. I want another switch named switch A to turn ON, when reed switch turns OFF after turning ON, but when the same reed switch turns ON (and OFF) again  (on collapsing the magnetic field in secondary coil) the switch A should do nothing. And then how would I reset the reed switch to detect the change in magnetic field again?

*Timing diagram (edited on request).*

```
              __    __    __    __    __    __    __    __    __
    Reed  ___|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__|  |__

                 __          __          __          __          __
Switch A  ______|  |________|  |________|  |________|  |________|
```

I couldn't find it on internet, can somebody please draw the circuit to achieve the same?

Comment: What resets the circuit?  In other words, how do you make it so that the reed switch becomes active again?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this setup? It sounds odd and I'm not convinced that what you are doing will result in anything useful so, what are you trying to achieve? Current isn't induced; voltage is induced. A reed switch is not a detector of current - it detects magnetism.

Comment: @DwayneReid That's another thing I want to achieve, thanks for highlighting.

Comment: @Andyaka I want to utilize the flux of permanent magnet and convert it into electricity. I have made changes in my question that you have highlighted, thanks!

Comment: The magnet's flux will not be converted to electricity - it will just bias the magnetic field and possibly cause core saturation when the added flux from the input signal is of the same polarity.

Comment: @Andyaka I am trying to make a simplest (for testing) version of this: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7830065B2/en

Comment: Good luck with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111488/discussion-between-yogie-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Too busy. Try and explain in your question what you are trying to achieve and why you think it will work. I'm not ploughing through a patent with all the jargon to figure out if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: I've added in a timing diagram showing the switch sequencing and reset functions but you need to edit it to clarify what you want and how to reset it.

Comment: I want to warn OP that grant of a patent is not a guarantee that the patented invention will actually work. But I suggest OP to give a clear timing diagram as mentioned above.

Comment: When you use electricity to generate electricity, it's called a "transformer". The permanent magnets add nothing to the process, and you can't get more power out than what you put in -- as long as you avoid saturation, it's about as efficient as any other transformer that uses more conventional construction.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the suggestion! I have edited the diagram in question for better understanding the requirement.

Comment: You may also have to show the `reset` signal in your diagram. Otherwise it can be seen that `A` is again going high after two cycles.

Comment: For prototyping purposes, I'd just use an Arduino

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic.

[image]

And here's the timing diagram.

[image]

Relay 'A' would set and reset on alternate pulses of the reed switch.

Comment: I am new to this, so can you please label what S and K are, so I can use those keywords to google them and learn myself? Thanks for answering!!

Comment: Hi Yogie, 'S' is the reed switch. The 'K's are electromagnetic relays. You are most welcome!